# How do I write a query that returns all documents whose date is between two dates?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a database of events and I would like to find all events in a given month. The approach I'm taking is to find all events whose date is greater than, say February 1, 2015, and less than or equal to February 28, 2015. Here is the code I have:

```
var start = '2015-02-01T00:00:00:000Z';
var end = '2015-02-28T00:00:00:000Z';
Event
    .find({
        'start_date': {
            '$gte' : start,
            '$lte' : end
        }
    })
    .sort({start_date: 1})
    .exec(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR = ' + err);
    } else {
        month = data;
        console.log('month' = JSON.stringify(month));
        ... // do other stuff
    }
});
```

My query always comes back empty, even though I have records in my database that should be returned. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE--------------------------------------------------------

Here is the schema I'm using:

```
var eventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title : String,
    details : String,
    start_date : Date,
    end_date : Date,
    created : {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

Comment: `'2015-02-01T00:00:00:000Z'` should be `'2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z'`. There is a dot between seconds and milliseconds, not a colon.

Comment: Oh, and you'd need to call `new Date(start)` on that string.

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't return any data.

Comment: `start_date: { $lte: new Date('2015-02-28T00:00:00.000Z') }` This should work (works in my data). The only other thing I see is `console.log('month' = JSON.stringify(month))` should be +, not =

Comment: The typo in the console.log was only added on SO. It's not in the original code. Still not sure why it doesn't work.

Comment: If that's the case, the issue isn't related to this code. [chat] if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good explanation of how to get around this issue can be found in the article [Querying for a Date Range (Specific Month or Day)](http://web.archive.org/web/20141205210712/http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/) which essentially suggests that you construct Date instances representing the start and end of the month used to do the range query (bearing in mind that in the `Date()` constructor, the month argument is 0-based index i.e. starts counting at 0, not 1. On the other hand, the days start counting at 1):

```
var start = new Date(2015, 1, 1);
var end = new Date(2015, 2, 1);

Event.find({
        'start_date': {
            '$gte' : start,
            '$lt' : end
        }
    })
    .sort({start_date: 1})
    .exec(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR = ' + err);
    } else {
        month = data;
        console.log('month' = JSON.stringify(month));
        ... // do other stuff
    }
});
```

You could also try querying using the ISODate and see if it makes a difference:

```
'start_date': {
     $gte: ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
     $lt: ISODate("2015-02-28T00:00:00.000Z")
 }
```